# Connection String not found in Config File

Tags: vb.net, wcf, ado.net, connection-string

I am new to ADO.NET, I am using MYSQL with WCF.

[image: Solution Explorer]

I have a WCF project with ADO.NET, the SalesSolLIB project has reference of SalesSolWCF, and SalesSolView has reference of SalesSolLib project.

The problem is ADO.Net entities are created in WCF and when run, the error comes as although the name is present in web.config file.

```
"No connection string named 'SalesSolEntities' could be found in the application config file."
```

WebConfig File

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="SalesSolEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/SalesSolDBModel.csdl|res://*/SalesSolDBModel.ssdl|res://*/SalesSolDBModel.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=localhost;user id=root;password=surpavan;persist security info=True;database=salessol;old guids=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Code in WCF file:

```
 Dim DB As New SalesSolEntities()
 DB.Database.Connection.Open()   
 DB.Database.Connection.Close()
 Return "test"
```

Code in SalesSolLib:

```
Dim service As New SalesSolWCF.ContactService
Dim errormsg As String = service.SaveContact(wcfcontact, IsNewContact)
```

However, through browsing, I found that connection string must be all the projects, however, why would I need to use WCF if connection string is needed in all projects, please advice how this can be solved, I don't want to put connection string in all projects or did I do wrong?

I am using Entity Framework 5.0 and the WCF Service Application as wcf project type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling your WCF services the wrong way. You do not add the reference by simply adding reference to DLL, you need to expose WCF endpoints via MEX, and then add reference by using "Add Service Reference".

What you've done now is that you're using your WCF not as a a service but just as a simple class that you make an instance off and then call it's methods. That is not how WCF services should be used, and that is why you get "connection string" missing error. Method in your class talks to database, so when you create instance of that class in other project, and call that method, that project must also have matching connection string. Basically it is all wrong, should not be done this way.

WCF services must be hosted either as self-hosted in your application or within IIS. I'd suggest that you go and take some basic WCF tutorial, otherwise what I just wrote will not make much of a sense to you.

Comment: Yup, that was a silly mistake, but took 3 days from me.  Thank you for the answer.

Comment: No problems, glad that I could help :)